# How to change values

Tags: excel, replace, unique-values

In Excel I have a range of numbers that need to equal something. So I have the number totaled in a column showing as below, then in the next column, depending on the range, I need it to equal something else. `(1-8) =.25; (9-15)=.5; (16-19)=.75 (20+)=1` This what I need it to look like:

```
COLM A   COLM B

(1-8)      .25
```

Comment: Try `=LOOKUP(A1,{0,1,8,16,20},{0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1})`. see [LOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lookup-function-HP010069832.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=IF(A2<20,IF(A2<16,IF(A2<9,If(A2>=1,.25,"Error"),.5),.75),1)`

This will show "Error" if you column A provides a number less than 1, or a blank.